# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to persist a new object into the database, but i am getting this error:

> SQL Error: 156, SQLState: S0001
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'key'.

**What I am doing**

```
Bucket bucket = new Bucket();
bucket.setKey(key);
bucket.setValue(value);


entityManager.persist(bucket);
```

I believe this error is due to the keyword 'key' being used in sql statements causing this.  Is there a native query that I can use to insert rows into my table?

My table has these three columns, with Id being auto-generated.

**Bucket:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Bucket {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id; //auto allocation of PK
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

Comment: The variable name might be causing the issue. Which database are you using?

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/escape-sql-reserved-keywords-jpa-hibernate/

Comment: I am using MSSQL. I will try to escape the keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Martin Smith for the help. Just one simple change and the issue was resolved.

**Bucket:**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Bucket {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id; //auto allocation of PK
    @Column(name = "\"key\"")
    private String key;
    @Column(name = "\"value\"")
    private String value;
}
```